How to know which user did reboot or shutdown when multiple desktop sessions are active?
I have a Ubuntu installation where multiple users have desktop sessions at the same time, some over XRDP and another directly on VT7. How can I find out which of these users initiated a shutdown or reboot, e.g by the XRDP mechanism

or by the systray popup menu?

For example like in Windows system in event viewer I can see which user did restart or shutdown by that the user click on button in each session even in RDP so the same I search to do for Linux system
None of the users will use the command-line to perform shutdown or restart.

Hi, and welcome to the site. I took the liberty to rephrase the question to make it easier to understand for contributors. If you feel the edit has gone against your original intentions, feel free to roll back.

@AdminBee I appreciate your help, But still in the process of powering off or restarting the PC I need to see how can be written on the log the user initiated it because after system comes up I check this, I will give example to describe better what I search for

XY bryh! Failing that: see sudo logs.

You're welcome to implement the feature yourself, currently it doesn't exist.
I filed a feature request more than a year ago:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/27847
Actually it's actively been worked on but it's yet to be merged:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/28579
You can grab the patchset and apply it to your system in case you don't want to wait for months/years before it reaches your distro.

Yes I see you requested, also please request for XRDP because there also have buttons of shutdown and reboot

XRDP will work as well regardless because it's just a session, so the PID will be logged and that should be enough to establish the user.

In openSUSE LEap 15.5 I found these after having powered off the system via GNOME menu:
polkitd[1721]: Operator of unix-session:2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:root to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.freedesktop.login1.power-off for system-bus-name::1.65 [/usr/lib/gnome-session-binary --systemd-service --session=gnome] (owned by unix-user:windl)
...
systemd-logind[1826]: System is powering down.

See the "owned by unix-user:" part.
